# Python 3.x how to get http version (using requests library)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Preferably using the requests library

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK        <-- I want this...
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

That property doesn't seem to be provided http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response

Is there a way to access the raw response string?

I found http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content
but I'm not seeing any content

```
r = requests.head(uri, stream=True)
print(r.raw.read(10)) # -> b''
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you want is this. Calling version on raw will give you HTTP version. (I found the example of server running HTTP 1.0 using Shodan for testing purposes)

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://104.71.136.252/", timeout=60, verify=False)
>>> response.raw.version
10
>>> response = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com", timeout=60, verify=False)
>>> response.raw.version
11
```

This is not mentioned in the docs directly, I found it by using PyCharm's autocomplete feature. But I have looked into it. The reason why is HTTP version returned as integer is historical.

Requests for python3 uses urllib3. Urllib3's class urllib3.response.HTTPResponse is backwards compatible with httplib’s HTTPResponse see [urllib3 docs](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=version#module-urllib3.response)

Now if it's backwards compatible you have to check documentation for httplib and if you search you'll find

> HTTP protocol version used by server. 10 for HTTP/1.0, 11 for HTTP/1.1.

Here is the exact link [HTTPResponse.version](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html?highlight=version#httplib.HTTPResponse.version)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be exactly what I want but why is the version returned as an int? I'm trying to find it in the source code but can't figure out where.

Comment: Can I assume that HTTP/2.0 will return 20? I tried https://http2.golang.org/ and it returns 11. Live headers says that the server is returning HTTP/2.0 OK. I just realized that my example shows a request... Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think it's as straightforward as returning 20 with HTTP 2.0. Check the RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-3.2